# download historical data in 4H time frame

Tags: python, yfinance

I use this code to download historical data from Yahoo finance in 1H time frame. Is there any way to download the data in 4H time frame?

```
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download(tickers_list,interval='1h', start='2022-10-25')['Close']
```

Normally the command  `yf.download` has 1 hour time frame but doesn't have 4-hour.

Comment: I just spent about 10 minutes digging through the source code, and there doesn't seem to be a way to even trick it into doing 4 hour intervals. [yf.download source](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/fb5c67b3bddb103f4b53f2e2274355a3c166b3d7/yfinance/multi.py#L32). About as close as you can get is `90m`.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy thank you. Is there any way to convert 1H data to 4H data? I mean, is it possible to delete 3 observations from each 4 observations and make a dataset based on the close price of the 4th hour?

Comment: I'm sure you can manipulate the data however you like once you have it all.